# This condition will always return 'true' since the types 'string[]' and 'DeliveryTypeEnum' have no overlap.ts(2367)

Tags: typescript, next.js, nestjs

hey guys im junior and need some help

```
        if (query.deliveryType && query.deliveryType != DeliveryTypeEnum.EITHER) {
            search.push({
                terms: {
                    "deliveryType.keyword": [query.deliveryType, DeliveryTypeEnum.EITHER],
                },
            });
        }
```

delivery type is string array

```
and error is :This condition will always return 'true' since the types 'string[]' and 'DeliveryTypeEnum' have no overlap. typescirpt (2367)
```

im getting error here `query.deliveryType && query.deliveryType != DeliveryTypeEnum.EITHER`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and in particular ask a question at all. 

Comment: Why are you trying to compare a `string[]` to a `DeliveryTypeEnum`?

Comment: Are you attempting to check if the deliveryType is one of the ENUM values?

Answer (score 1):

Since `query.deliveryType` is an Array. you can use array functions like **includes**. so if your array of delivery Types did not include EITHER then you can what ever you want.

so you can do this:

```
if (query.deliveryType && !query.deliveryType.includes(DeliveryTypeEnum.EITHER)){
   // Do what ever you want!
}
```

You can learn more about includes function in this link:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Answer (score 0):

The error tries to tell you that the `if` statement probably does not what you want it to do, because the type of the variable `query.deliveryType` already indicates that it will never be `DeliveryTypeEnum.EITHER`.